# Xcode: Accidentally deleted info.plist and prefix.pch from 'build settings'

Tags: ios, xcode

is there any way to restore it? The file is intact, so its just the pointers in build settings menu which got deleted.

I tried restarting the xcode and cleaning the project, but nothing happens and I cant run my app in the simulator anymore either.

Comment: Have you been using source control?

Comment: I think I may have disabled it when I created the project

Comment: Well now you've learned your lesson about source control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try adding the file to the project with the "Add File..." dialogue, though you'll have to clean before building again.

Comment: Thanks!, i made a custom rule, added the files manually and it worked.